# How to create a DataTemplate with a StackPanel of a variable number of StackPanels

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate, stackpanel

I am trying to create a DataTamplate which should contain a StackPanel with a certain number of StackPanels.

```
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Rectangle Fill="Aqua" Margin="2" Height="100" Width="50"  VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

The code snippet above is just for a better understanding of my desired result, as the elements in the imbricated StackPanel will be binded.

This generates the following error message:
VisualTree of ItemsPanelTemplate must be a single element.

Any alternatives that could work?

Comment: how do you want to specify that **certain** number?

Comment: The first StackPanel will be binded to an object with a certain number of properties.

Comment: and you want to have an inner stackPanel for each object in list?

Comment: Yes, and that StackPanel will contain a fixed number of items binded to the propreties of the object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should `ItemsControl` with `ItemsSource` bound to your source list. In `ItemsControl.ItemsPanel` you can set which panel you want to use for items. In your case you should use `StackPanel` with `Orientation=Vertical` as `ItemsPanel`. See [first sample here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel.aspx). But vertical `StackPanel` is already default `ItemsPanel` so you can omit it.

Inner `StackPanel` should be specified as `ItemTemplate` in your `ItemsControl`.

Your XAML should look like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="...">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <!-- properties of your object should go here -->
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```